# Javascript code to change a span to an image with a link stopped working

Tags: javascript, html

I have some Javascript code that's supposed to load the contents of a text file, and based on that info, insert an image and link into a span.

The JS file is here: http://jewishmusicstream.com/ads/ads.js

It's supposed to insert an image into the main page on http://jewishmusicstream.com, in the mmusic and smusic divs/spans, but it seems to have stopped working.

Does anyone know what's wrong, and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with your browser's JavaScript debugger.  To open it in IE or FireFox, hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, in Chrome hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.  Here's what IE's JS debugger displays:

[image: Jewish Music Stream JavaScript Debugger Screen Shot]

You can instantly see that the error is on line 12.

You are getting this error because you are trying to read the `responseText` property of your `XMLHttpRequest` object before it is ready.  You can't read that property until after you have received some response from the server.  Remove that line of code.  You are already properly reading the `responseText` in the `readystatechange` handler, so just removing that line of code should fix it.  You'll have to do the same on line 48 where you have a similar pattern.

**Edit:**  By the way, you could really reduce your code by eliminating redundancies.  Just create one function and call it twice with the appropriate params:

```
function loadAd(adSpecUrl, containerId)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", adSpecUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            var lines = xhr.responseText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var src = lines[0];
            var href = lines[1];
            var w = lines[2];
            var h = lines[3];
            var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
            var link = container.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
            link.href = href;
            link.target = "_blank";
            var img = link.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
            img.src = src;
            img.width = w;
            img.height = h;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
loadAd("/ads/sm.txt", "smusic");
loadAd("/ads/mm.txt", "mmusic");
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew about the debugger, but didn't know where to look...
Question is, how can I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: @Issac - Just remove that line of code.  It looks like it doesn't really do anything and you don't need it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I took those lines out - I must have left the lines in there accidentally. Problem is, it still doesn't seem to be working...
Any ideas?

Comment: @Isaac - It's working for me.  I opened your site in IE, Chrome, and FF, and I see the ads.  Clicking them works.  What problem are you still facing?

Comment: Didn't work for me in Chrome for some reason...
Thanks for your code, I knew there was a way to do it shorter :)
Lemme try that, and see if it works - thanks so much!

Comment: @IsaacL let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1159/discussion-between-gilly3-and-isaacl)